# Getting the image resources from jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css

I have a working script from jsfiddle, but in the css file its referencing images. It works on jsfiddle.

What I did in my project is:
Created blank script files and named them the same name that was on jsfiddle. 
then copied the script file code from the script on jsfiddle and pasted into the blank file and saved it. The javascript seems to be working in my project, but the lightbox doesnt look right and its probably because the css file is referencing images. Where on jsfiddle can I get the images that are referenced in the css?

http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/trnZS/2/

I found the png files on the need, and added them to my App_Themes/Theme1/ folder and then changed the css to background-image: url('App_Themes/Theme1/fancybox.png'); but it still is not seeing the images. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Is this a valid way to reference an image in a css file?

```
background-image: url('../css/images/fancybox.png');
```

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't seem to be working anymore...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine here?

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17927147/StackOverflow/Dog.png]

If you want to inspect elements I recommend Google Chrome and it's built in console, I like it much better then firefox + firebug.

Comment: I am having problems changing the paths in the css.

Comment: @NickLaMarca try adding a `/` to the start URL. - `url('/App_Themes/Theme1/fancybox.png')`

Answer (score 1):

Firefox + Firebug, right click, inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the loading animation and the close button images, do you also have the [FancyBox plugin](http://fancybox.net) installed? That's where jsfiddle seems to be referencing those images from.

If you don't want the plugin, the png files look like sprites, are you setting the background position?