# Adding an image to a jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I'm wanting to use a little image/icon in a jsfiddle.

How do I go about this? Do I upload an image somewhere? Or are there URLs that you can pull from? The documentation didn't make it obvious (to me, at least). I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404545/adding-background-image-to-button-using-css-jsfiddle) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262068/getting-the-image-resources-from-jsfiddle), but the accompanying fiddles aren't showing an image.

I just want a 20px x 20px something to attach to an `<a>` to demo some CSS.

Comment: you can't upload anything to jsFiddle. Please either upload it to public dropbox folder or any other service which allows that. You can also use image placeholders if image's content is not important - http://placekitten.com/

Comment: @zalun Thanks. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reposted as an answer - you can't upload anything to jsFiddle. Please either upload it to public dropbox folder or any other service which allows that. You can also use image placeholders if image's content is not important - placekitten.com

Comment: Noting that it seems they require attribution: http://placekitten.com/attribution.html (No idea what the minimum requirement for *attribution* is, and especially since jsFiddle has the code displayed.)

Answer (score 2):

Your other option is to embed the image as base64 encoded content.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme for details on doing that.